# Using field as input for multiple ring buffer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, buffer

I have a feature class with points and I need to create two concentric circle with different distances for each point. Moreover the two surfaces do not have to overlap.

Can I use "multiple ring buffer"? And how I am able to add as an input features a field that  contains the distance to buffer each feature?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are faster without the "multiple ring buffer". It can process more polygons at once, but if I got you right, the distances are different for every input point.

Using the simple buffer tool twice has the following advantages:

- You can select an attribute field which contains the unique distances for every point (if you don't have such attribute yet, I would suggest creating two new attributes with the field calculator, e.g. buffer1 and buffer2).
- You can check the "Outside Polygons Only (optional)" box the second time to assure the second buffer doesn't contain the first one. However, you would have to modify your distances.

For example:

1. A Point needs two buffer distances: 10 and 50 meters.
2. Your Attributes for the buffer function  would be buffer1=10 and buffer2=50
3. Make the first buffer with "buffer1" in the "Distance/field" option.
4. To avoid an overlap of the second buffer, you need a new, third field, e.g. "buffer_delta". It is the remaining buffer from the first to the second. In our case it would be 50 - 10 = 40 meters. Use the field calculator to make this third field.
5. Make the second buffer based on your first but with "buffer_delta" in the "Distance/field" option. Make sure the  "Outside Polygons Only (optional)" box is checked.
6. Your result is one buffer from 0-10 meters and one from 10-50 meters.